# How do you install m2e-android-plugin in Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, maven, m2e

I am trying to get setup to use Maven and pom.xml files in Eclipse for my Android projects. I have Eclipse Indigo setup (m2e included), Android SDK installed, ADT installed. I am struggling to understand what it means to "Install the m2e-android-plugin" (I am always taken to [this page](http://rgladwell.github.com/m2e-android/) which provides instructions on installing it, but which I cannot follow) Specifically, when I go through the instruction on that page, after I complete all the steps in part 2, my structure does not have "Maven Dependencies" and my pom.xml file shows the following error:

```
Project build error: Unresolveable build extension: Plugin
com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2:android-maven-plugin:3.1.1 or one of its dependencies could 
not be resolved: The following artifacts could not be resolved: 
com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2:android-maven-plugin:jar:3.1.1, 
com.android.ddmlib:ddmlib:jar:r16, org.sonatype.sisu:sisu-inject-bean:jar:2.1.1,     
org.sonatype.sisu:sisu-guice:jar:no_aop:2.9.4, org.codehaus.plexus:plexus- archiver:jar:2.0.1, junit:junit:jar:3.8.1, 
org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-io:jar:2.0.1, org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:3.0, commons-jxpath:commons-
jxpath:jar:1.3, commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.0.1, org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:4.0, commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:
2.6, org.sonatype.aether:aether-util:jar:1.12: Failure to transfer 
com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2:android-maven-plugin:jar:3.1.1 from http://repo1.maven.org/
maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central 
has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact 
com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2:android-maven-plugin:jar:3.1.1 from/to central (http://
repo1.maven.org/maven2): No response received after 60000
```

along with:

```
Project build error: Unknown packaging: apk
```

on the line

```
<packaging>apk</packaging>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have tried set up a fresh second IDE myself and everything works as expected, suppose you have installed both Android SDK and Maven properly (better to use latest version), these are the only Eclipse plugins required to work with Mavenized Android Project:

- adt
- m2e
- m2e-android

Check out my screenshot `Help -> Install New Software... -> what is already installed`:

[image]

If you follow instructions from [this page](http://rgladwell.github.com/m2e-android/) starting with a new project, the <packaging> error is most likely due to earlie version of maven-release-plugin (if you do not explicitly specify one). By hovering mouse on <packaging> element in pom.xml, you should get some hint like:

> maven-resources-plugin prior to 2.4 is not supported by m2e. Use maven-resources-plugin version 2.4 or later.

Adding the following plugin under <plugins>:

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.5</version>
</plugin>
```

Then Right-click on new project and select Maven -> Update Project Configuration, this should fix all error and give you a working example.

Comment: I have tried to go through Eclipse Marketplace. When I click Install I get the following message "The following solutions are not available: Android Configurator For M2E Proceed with the installation anyways?"

Comment: Yea looks like it didnt't actually install it, and thus stuff still doesn't work...

Comment: Hm. It seems like everything is installed, but it doesn't work. http://imgur.com/TOnBo ,  http://imgur.com/MdFSF

Comment: Acording to the error log, it seems Maven doesn't download all required dependencies, note that it may take some time download all dependencies when start using Maven first time. check out your local maven repository (usually under your-profile/.m2/repository/) see if android-maven-plugin-3.1.1.jar is here /com/jayway/maven/plugins/android/generation2/android-maven-plugin/3.1.1, if not, try re-import the project several times or manually resolve all missing dependencies.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12519/discussion-between-leo-and-yorkw)

Comment: hey guys, if you're having problems installing m2e-android please report the issues against the project: https://github.com/rgladwell/m2e-android/issues/new

Comment: Isn't there any update site available to install the m2e-android plugin? I am using Eclipse + ADT that comes with the Android SDK. As a consequence, the menu option Help > Eclipse Marketplace isn't available.

Comment: The update site is not working, it says 404 error. Can someone please let me know what is the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem trying to install the android m2e in eclipse JUNO. 
Then tried to install through "Install new software" wizard, instead of market place.

Add the following as an update site and select "Android For Maven eclipse" from the listed softwares and install.

http://rgladwell.github.com/m2e-android/updates - Thanks to @NullNoname for providing the update site.

Comment: The link is not working for me. I get the message: _There isn't a GitHub Page here._ Could you please fix the link?