# Do I need to install an ADT plugin if I want to use Maven?

Tags: java, android, maven

Is it necessary to download and install ADT plugin into Eclipse, if I want to build all projects using maven?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a mavenized android project, if you are talking about build project from commandline, for instance, check out [some projects from GitHub](https://github.com/jayway/maven-android-plugin-samples/tree/master/helloflashlight) and do a `mvn clean install`, you only need install and setup:

- Android SDK
- Maven

If you are talking about develop/build project inside IDE like Eclipse, besides Android SDK and Maven, you need the following Eclipse plugins (all available via Eclipse Marketplace), in order to create/import and work on mavenized android project inside Eclipse:

- adt
- m2e (Maven Integration for Eclipse)
- m2e-android (Android Configurator for M2E)

Check out answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11023252/how-do-you-install-m2e-android-plugin-in-eclipse/11023584#11023584) and see screenshot of installed Eclipse plugin.

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to get your project to build by just relying on maven, but you'd miss out on debug tools, Android-specific editors, the simulator, the ADB shell...

Answer (score 0):

the ADT plugin is required as It holds the APIs though I am not familiar with maven It would probably be a good idea to install the android ADT to get these APIs. also included in the ADT is the system images and java files needed to build on to create an app.

as I said I am not familiar with maven but I would still recommend installing android ADT