# How to convert an existing Android project with Google API 4.2 to Maven

Tags: android, eclipse, maven, intellij-idea

I'm trying to use Maven for new projects, but this thing is confusing me at all.

In all examples they only use the Android default APIs, but I need the Google API as my application uses Google Maps. How can I use Google APIs?

This is an existing Android Project made on Eclipse (now I'm trying to use IntelliJ IDEA) and I'd like to start using Maven, so how can I convert the existing Project to Maven?

Thanks.

Comment: This question is related to http://stackoverflow.com/q/2449461/130224

Comment: Sorry about one of my questions being related to an existing one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To convert an Eclipse project to a Maven project, select the Java project in Eclipse and popup the context menu, then select "Configure" > "Convert to Maven Project".

Comment: This is causing an error. I cannot change the packaging attribute to APK and the google android dependency is not recognized.

Comment: I'm getting this on Eclipse: "Project build error: Unknown packaging: apk" and "Missing artifact com.google.android:android:jar:17"

Comment: That seems like a different issue. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/11023252 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/10610564.

Comment: Some description of how to fill in the resulting form would be helpful.  Does "version" matter?  What about "Packaging"?

Answer (score 1):

1. The maven-android-plugin aka android-maven-plugin talks about how to maven-ize your android project. http://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/wiki/GettingStarted
2. The Add-Ons such as maps, usb, gcm you'd need to use the maven-android-sdk-deployer. The documents spells out the exact xml to use in pom.xml
   https://github.com/mosabua/maven-android-sdk-deployer

Answer (score 0):

For the question about Google Api just put the following  code in the application tag of your AndroidManifest file

```
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
```

for the second question, i recommend you to make first the conversion in eclipse
following this tutorial  http://steveliles.github.com/converting_eclipse_adt_android_projects_to_build_with_maven.html
and after that you can import your maven project into IntelliJ IDEA