# Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2:android-maven-plugin:3.5.0:generate-sources

Tags: java, android, eclipse, maven, maven-3

I have an Android application, which is built using `pom.xml` file given below.  `mvn clean install` works without errors, but in Eclipse I get following errors:

```
Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2:android-maven-plugin:3.5.0:generate-sources (execution: default-generate-sources, phase: generate-sources)
Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2:android-maven-plugin:3.5.0:proguard (execution: default-proguard, phase: process-classes)
```

How can I fix them?

Here's the `pom.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>myapp-android</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>apk</packaging>
    <name>myappAndroidClient</name>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>achartengine</id>
            <name>Public AChartEngine repository</name>
            <url>https://repository-achartengine.forge.cloudbees.com/snapshot/</url>
        </repository>       
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
            <artifactId>android</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.1.4</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.2</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Make sure this (robolectric dependency) is below the android dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.pivotallabs</groupId>
            <artifactId>robolectric</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-RC4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.achartengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>achartengine</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0</version>
        </dependency>               
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.6</source>
                        <target>1.6</target>
                        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                    <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.5.0</version>

                    <extensions>true</extensions>

                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <sdk>
                            <!-- platform or api level (api level 4 = platform 1.6) -->
                            <platform>17</platform>
                            <path>C:\Program Files\adt-bundle-windows-x86\adt-bundle-windows-x86\sdk</path>
                        </sdk>
                    </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <reporting>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>javancss-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <targetJdk>1.7</targetJdk>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <configLocation>altruix-checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
                    <includeTestSourceDirectory>true</includeTestSourceDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <formats>
                        <format>html</format>
                        <format>xml</format>
                    </formats>
                    <instrumentation>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>**/*Test.class</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </instrumentation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <inputEncoding>UTF-8</inputEncoding>
                    <outputEncoding>UTF-8</outputEncoding>
                    <locales>en</locales>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>jdepend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>
</project>
```

**Update 1 (06.03.2013)**: Here's the list of installed plugins.

[image]

**Update 2 (08.03.2013):** Below you can find the updated `pom.xml`. Now I get another error - `Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2:android-maven-plugin:3.5.0:proguard (execution: default-proguard, phase: process-classes)` at the place marked by `<!-- Error occurs here -->` in the XML code below.

```
    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.6</source>
                        <target>1.6</target>
                        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                            <pluginExecutions>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                                        <versionRange>[3.5.0,)</versionRange>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>generate-sources</goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action>
                                        <ignore />
                                    </action>
                                </pluginExecution>
                            </pluginExecutions>
                        </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                    <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.5.0</version>
                    <extensions>true</extensions>

                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.5</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin> <!-- Error occurs here -->
                <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <sdk>
                        <!-- platform or api level (api level 4 = platform 1.6) -->
                        <platform>17</platform>
                        <path>C:\Program Files\adt-bundle-windows-x86\adt-bundle-windows-x86\sdk</path>
                    </sdk>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

**Update 3 (08.03.2013):** When I change the `pom.xml` file in this way

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
    <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
            <pluginExecutions>
                <pluginExecution>
                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                        <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                        <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <versionRange>[3.5.0,)</versionRange>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate-sources</goal>
                            <goal>proguard</goal>
                            <goal>emma</goal>
                            <goal>dex</goal>
                            <goal>internal-pre-integration-test</goal>
                            <goal>internal-integration-test</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                    <action>
                        <ignore />
                    </action>
                </pluginExecution>
            </pluginExecutions>
        </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
    <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.0</version>
    <extensions>true</extensions>

</plugin>
```

and run the application from Eclipse, I get following error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: co.altruix.ccp.android.impl.viewtype2fragmentmapper.DefaultViewTypeToFragmentMapper
    at co.altruix.ccp.android.impl.activities.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:22)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1054)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2097)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

When I run the same application using `mvn clean install; mvn android:emulator-start; mvn android:deploy`, everything works fine.

**Update 4 (11.03.2013 00:24 MSK):** Here's the list of installed plugins in my new eclipse installation:

[image: List of plugins]

**Update 5 (12.03.2013 23:22 MSK):** Here's the classpath (achartengine seems to be included):

[image: Classpath]

You can also download my [Eclipse installation](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/11776689/2013_03_12_android-eclipse.7z).

Comment: It looks like you are missing a [m2e connector](http://objectledge.org/confluence/display/TOOLS/M2E+Connectors) required to integrate the maven-android-plugin to Eclipse.  Have you [installed the connector](http://rgladwell.github.com/m2e-android/)?

Comment: I can't. There is no menu item `Help -> Eclipse Marketplace` in my IDE.

Comment: @sbk See **update 1** with a list of all installed Eclipse plugins.

Comment: Did you download the Eclipse from the Android web site rather than from eclipse.org directly?

Comment: Looks as though you already have m2e-android installed. Can you verify this?

Comment: @RicardoGladwell 1) AFAIR I downloaded Eclipse from the Android web site. 2) How can I verify that m2e-android is installed?

Comment: It should be in the list of installed plugins as 'Android Connector'. If that fails you can try installing Eclipse from eclipse.org and install the plugins yourself.

Comment: @RicardoGladwell Re-installing eclipse from eclipse.org didn't help. I still get the `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: co.altruix.ccp.android.impl.viewtype2fragmentmapper.DefaultViewTypeToFragmentMapper` exception when launching the app from eclipse.

Comment: @DmitriPisarenko, _How can I verify that m2e-android is installed?_ See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11023252/how-do-you-install-m2e-android-plugin-in-eclipse/11023584#11023584).

Comment: @yorkw Thanks. See "Update 4" with a list of plugins in my eclipse IDE.

Comment: How did you import the project? The correct way is to use `File - Import... - Maven - Existing Maven Projects` import the mavenized android project.

Comment: @DmitriPisarenko is the achartengine dependency appearing in your classpath? Did you verify if m2e-android is installed?

Comment: @yorkw I deleted the existing project, then imported it as you explained. I get same results (`NoClassDefFoundError`).

Comment: @RicardoGladwell Regarding m2e-android - as you can see in the screenshot in "Update 4", there is a plugin called "Android configurator for M2E", from which I conclude that m2e-android is installed.

Comment: @DmitriPisarenko cool, is the achartengine dependency appearing in your classpath?

Comment: @RicardoGladwell According to the project properties - yes. See the screenshot in "Update 5".

Comment: To help you debug my issue, I added the link to 7zipped archive of my eclipse installation.

Comment: See the link below the screenshot in "Update 5".

Comment: @All: Are there any pieces of information that might help you answer the question (and which I didn't provide yet) and get the bounty?

Answer (score 3):

One way to solve it is by adding the following section to your **pom.xml** (or parent pom.xml):

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
   <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
   <version>1.0.0</version>
   <configuration>
      <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
         <pluginExecutions>
            <pluginExecution>
               <pluginExecutionFilter>
                  <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                  <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                  <versionRange>[3.5.0,)</versionRange>
                  <goals>                                                               
                     <goal>generate-sources</goal>      
                     <goal>proguard</goal>
                     <goal>emma</goal>
                     <goal>dex</goal>
                     <goal>apk</goal>
                     <goal>internal-pre-integration-test</goal>
                     <goal>internal-integration-test</goal>                                         
                  </goals>
               </pluginExecutionFilter>
               <action>
                  <execute />
               </action>
            </pluginExecution>
         </pluginExecutions>
      </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
   </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: I tried your recommendation. Now I get another error - details see "Update 2" above.

Comment: Just add the goal to the goals tag: <goal>proguard</goal>. The same issue you will probably have with other goals from the plugin: apk, emma, dex, ... Just add them with the goals tag.

Comment: Thanks. After I added the `proguard` goal, I can't deploy the app to the emulator because one of my class files is missing (this didn't occur before). I'll send the stack trace in a couple of hours.

Comment: You can find detailed information about my problem with ProGuard in "Update 3".

Comment: This will not resolve the issue, but simply disable any integration with Eclipse/m2e.

Comment: No reason to downvote. Try changing 'ignore' to 'execute' for some of the goals.

Comment: Project build error: Unknown packaging: apk" , when i try to use this. can i have a sample pom.xml complete file.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue on my **Spring Tool Suite 4** (*Version: 4.6.0.RELEASE*).

**How i fixed it.**

**Step 1.** Hover over the execution element in your pom.xml

[image]

**Step 2.** Select either "***Mark goal compile as ignored in pom.xml***" or "***Mark goal compile as ignored in eclipse preferences***" depending on whether you want to ignore the execution at your project level or on your IDE level.

**Step 3.** Right click on your project in the package explorer and "***Maven --> Update project***"