# Develop with Eclipse an Android Maven project

Tags: android, eclipse, maven, android-maven-plugin

I am trying to run [the official HelloFlashlight sample](https://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/wiki/Samples) provided by the [android-maven-plugin](https://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/), but Eclipse displays this error.

> Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2:android-maven-plugin:3.8.2:consume-aar (execution: default-consume-aar, phase: compile)

Here is what I did.

1. Create the HelloFlashlight project in Eclipse
2. "Configure / Convert to Maven Project"

I tried using `mvn eclipse:eclipse`, but I learned that [it was not a good idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10564684/how-to-fix-error-updating-maven-project-unsupported-iclasspathentry-kind-4).

I added the XML snippet provided [in another SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15234536/plugin-execution-not-covered-by-lifecycle-configuration-com-jayway-maven-plugin/15294781), but all I got was a new error (in addition to the previous one).

> Execution default-apk of goal com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2:android-maven-plugin:3.8.2:apk failed: Unable to load the mojo 'apk' (or one of its required components) from the plugin 'com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2:android-maven-plugin:3.8.2' (com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2:android-maven-plugin:3.8.2:apk:default-apk:package)

I am missing something?

My configuration:

- Eclipse Kepler Service Release 1 (Build id: 20130919-0819)
- m2e - Maven Integration for Eclipse - 1.4.0.20130601-0317
- Android Development Tools - 22.3.0.v201310242005-887826
- Android Configurator for M2E - 0.4.3

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15234536/plugin-execution-not-covered-by-lifecycle-configuration-com-jayway-maven-plugin

Comment: I updated my question to reflect this SO post.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to add mojo as a dependency

this might help:

http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/writing-plugins-sect-custom-plugin.html#writing-plugins-simple-java-mojo

taken from:

https://github.com/jayway/maven-android-plugin-samples/tree/master/helloflashlight

or this tutorial might help:

http://www.androidhive.info/2013/04/android-developing-flashlight-application/

Comment: While this answer may theoretically answer the question, [it is better](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the links for reference.

Comment: The issue is only with Eclipse. Running `mvn install android:deploy android:run` from the command line works fine.