# Last ADT update (22.6.3) spoiled my Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, maven, eclipse-plugin

I am using mavenized library project with the following plugin:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
            <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.0</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <nativeLibrariesDirectory>ignored</nativeLibrariesDirectory>
                <attachSources>true</attachSources>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

But after the last update of the ADT (22.6.3) everything went wrong, the JAR is not built by Eclipse, and I got error messages of lyfecicle like this:

> Description Resource Path Location Type Conflicting lifecycle mapping
>   (plugin execution
>   "com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2:android-maven-plugin:3.6.0:proguard
>   (execution: default-proguard, phase: process-classes)"). To enable
>   full functionality, remove the conflicting mapping and run
>   Maven->Update Project Configuration. pom.xml /actionbarsherlock line 1
>   Maven Project Build Lifecycle Mapping Problem

I have followed those instructions in order to solve the problems, and indeed they are gone, but the JAR is not being built.
Also tried with this: [com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2: Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13554694/com-jayway-maven-plugins-android-generation2-plugin-execution-not-covered-by-li/16426897#16426897) but no success.

This is my Eclipse (Kepler) Installation Details:

- Android Configurator for M2E 1.0.0   me.gladwell.eclipse.m2e.android.feature.feature.group   Gladwell.me
- Android DDMS 22.6.3.v201404151837-1123206    com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms.feature.group  The Android Open Source Project
- Android Development Tools    22.6.3.v201404151837-1123206    com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group   The Android Open Source Project
- Android Hierarchy Viewer 22.6.3.v201404151837-1123206    com.android.ide.eclipse.hierarchyviewer.feature.group   The Android Open Source Project
- Android Traceview    22.6.3.v201404151837-1123206    com.android.ide.eclipse.traceview.feature.group The Android Open Source Project
- Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers   2.0.2.20140224-0000 epp.package.jee null
- Genymotion Eclipse Tools 1.0.3.201403261147  com.genymobile.genymotion.ide.eclipse.feature.group Genymobile
- m2e - Maven Integration for Eclipse  1.4.1.20140328-1905 org.eclipse.m2e.feature.feature.group   Eclipse.org - m2e
- m2e - slf4j over logback logging (Optional)  1.4.1.20140328-1905 org.eclipse.m2e.logback.feature.feature.group   Eclipse.org - m2e
- Tracer for OpenGL ES 22.6.3.v201404151837-1123206    com.android.ide.eclipse.gldebugger.feature.group    The Android Open Source Project

Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2:android-maven-plugin:3.5.0:generate-sources](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15234536/plugin-execution-not-covered-by-lifecycle-configuration-com-jayway-maven-plugin)

Comment: Yes, is more or less the same, but then there's no solution but disable any integration with Eclipse/m2e?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had this issue an after rebuilding the whole environment again (newest Eclipse Juno J2EE + newest maven-android plugin) figured out that the problem was exactly in the maven-android plugin. It has an update issue: output directory set to target/classes instead of bin/classes. This can be fixed unchecking the "Allow output folder for source folders" box in the source tab of the build path of each project. For more info about that please check this: 
https://github.com/rgladwell/m2e-android/issues/219

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem.

I end up installing the latest version of Eclipse, and then add the Android software repo on it and everything is working now.

Answer (score 0):

Try change version to 3.9.0-rc.1:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
    <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.9.0-rc.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Has the same issue ! I simply downloaded the last version of Eclipse here : http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#ExistingIDE

It includes the Android SDK => nothing else to download. Works perfectly directly.

And what is really great is that my whole workspace (projects opened in Eclipse, signatures, etc...) has been recovered. Nothing to do ! Just download, place in any folder on your computer (a Mac in my case), and start to work with the last Eclipse version.

Really happy :)